# what are the appropriate way of writing a function for a delete button for a calculator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calculator, calculation

I am a react beginner!  have been trying to write a code inside deletehandler function wish was assign to delete button, whereby if the button is clicked, one or more value on the calculator screen should be erase or removed.

How can I get this done?

This is my code so far;

```
const deleteClickHandler = () => {

    let num = calc.num ? toLocaleString(removeSpaces(-calc.num)) : 0;
    let res = calc.res ? toLocaleString(removeSpaces(-calc.res)) : 0;

    setCalc({
        ...calc,
        num: (num /= splice(0, -1)),
        res: (res /= splice(0, -1)),
        sign: "",
    });
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble reading this code. What is `calc.num`. What is `calc.res`? Why is there a `-` in the argument to `removeSpaces()`?  What does `setCalc` do? What does `splice()` do? Usually this is an array method, but this isn't attached to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing the last index in an array, for instance, you can use pop()

```
let numbers = [71, 6, 3 , 45, 5]; 
numbers.pop();
```

you can also apply this kind of approach with your res KEY

```
// [71, 6, 3, 45]
```